# VS2012 is missing "format document" feature

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have VS2012 Pro installed, and there is no "Format Document" feature under Edit -> Advanced.  I used this all the time in VS2010, and would like to continue using it.  Is it just not available in the Pro version of 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS2012 the command is there as well. It depends on the current settings. I still have it under Edit -> Advanced where it shows the Ctrl + E + D shortcut that is assigned to it.
Please check the following:

- Go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard and check which additional keyboard mapping scheme is applied in the drop down on top. For me it states "Visual C# 2005"
- Then, as Jarek already suggested search in the 'Show command containing' for 'Edit.FormatDocument' and see if there is a shortcut assigned now.
- Which kind of environment have you choosen when installing VS 2012? Was it for C#? If you want to change that you can do it unter Tools -> Import and Export Settings as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zbhkx167.aspx)
- Last but not least I'm not sure any more if this function actually is part of Visual Studio 2012 itself (I'm 98% sure it is, but 98 is not 100) so please check if installing the [PowerCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) extension solves this issue (Even though the name suggests that they are only for VS 2010 they also support VS 2012). Note that the PowerCommands are also integrated now in the [ProductivityPowerTools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) directly.

Answer (score 3):

It is missing from the menu but you can still access is via shortcut

```
Ctrl+E,D
```

Comment: This is what VS2012 says in response: `"The key combination (Ctrl+E, D) is not a command."`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does nothing.  Not even a message in the status line.  :-(

Comment: ok, go to Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard
In 'Show commands containing' type Edit.FormatDocument -> from there you can see what shortcut is assigned to the command and change it if you want.

Comment: This works with Web Developer as your default Visual Studio settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about other types of files other than .cs, I think VS will generally go by the file extension.

I was trying to edit a .txt file with xml in it and couldn't get the menu option or the shortcut keys to work. Then renamed the file to .xml and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Reformat Selection" in XML Editor toolbar.